# Can't save changes in EF Core : an error occurred while updating the entities. Invalid Object Name 'CartClothesItem'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I use a many-to-many relationship. When I want to add an item to the cart I get this exception:

> An error occurred while updating the entities. Invalid object name 'CartClothesItem'

I don't even have the entity named 'CartClothesItem'.

This is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddItemIntoCart(int userId, int itemId)
{
    if (userId <= 0 || itemId <= 0) 
         return BadRequest("The parameters are invalid!");

    var userCart =  _context.Carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == userId);
    var item = _context.ClothesItems.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ClothesItemId == itemId);

    if (item == null) 
        return NotFound("The item doesn't exist");

    if (userCart == null) 
        return NotFound("The user doesn't exist");

    if (userCart.Items.Where(i => i.ClothesItemId == itemId).Any())
        return BadRequest("You already have this item in the cart");

    userCart.Items.Add(item);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok("The item was successfully added into your cart!");
}
```

Item model class:

```
public class СlothesItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ClothesItemId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The price can't be negative.")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ClothesItem_EnsureThisClothesTypeExists]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }

    public СlothesItem()
    {
        Photos = new List<Photo>();
        Carts = new List<Cart>();
    }
}
```

Cart model class:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<СlothesItem> Items { get; set; }

    public Cart()
    {
        Items = new List<СlothesItem>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to Include `Items`: ` _context.Carts.Include(c => c.Items).SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == userId)`

Comment: Your issue mentioned `updating the entities`, so is it possible that after adding to the database, then triggered another update process?